# Update an image on PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php

I try to edit an image in my data base but I have a error message : **Notice: Undefined index: id**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

I am capable to add an image but I would like to know how to update an image ???

```
<?php

// Connexion à la base de donnée

include('config_bd.php');



// Vérifications des inputs

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/" .basename($_FILES['image']['name']));

    $nom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nom']);
    $image = htmlspecialchars($_FILES['image']['name']);



    if(empty($nom) || empty($image)){

        if(empty($nom)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le champ nom est vide.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($image)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le champ image est vide.</font><br/>";
        }

    }else{
        $update = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE clubs SET nom='$nom',image='$image'WHERE id='$id'");


        echo "<font color='green'>L'entrée a été enregistré!.";
        echo "<br/><a href='view.php'>Consulter</a>";

           }

    }


$id = $_GET['id'];

$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE id='$id' ");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){

    echo "<div id='img_div'>";
    echo "<p>" .$res['nom']."</p>";
    echo "<img src='images/" .$res['image']."'>";
    echo "</div>";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Titre de la page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="nom" >

                <input type="file" name="image"><br /><br />

                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>>


            </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Thank you a lot for a potential answer.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Side note: Why are you doing `if(empty($nom)`... then checking for it again *after?* Same thing for `empty($image)`.

Comment: `font` tag was deprecated about 10 years ago, and `htmlspecialchars` wont protect you from SQL injection https://3v4l.org/Eul4K